# How do I set how many times to run a method? (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, cocos2d-iphone, numbers

I have a method to add an enemy, and I want to know how I can make it so I run it a certain number of times (say 10). I call the method with a scheduler in cocos2d and by doing [self addEnemy];
Need any more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selector you schedule is `methodA`:

```
[self schedule:@selector(methodA:) interval:1/60];
```

then a simple way to do what you are looking for is:

```
- (void) methodA:(ccTime)adelta {
    static int counter = 10;
    if (--counter >= 0) {
         //-- do your processing
    } else {
        counter = 10; //-- this in case you want to reschedule the method at some later point
        [self unschedule:@selector(methodA:)];
    }
}
```

If you prefer it, you could use an ivar in your class to track the number of repetitions.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is how can I implement this with my enemies being within a spritesheet? I don't get any issues when I build, but when I run, 3 seconds (the interval I set) after the scene is open, it freezes. I can't click on the back button or see the crash results, because it won't end.

Comment: possibly you should schedule the method only after you have loaded the spritesheet... if you run under the debugger, you can possibly see the statement that made it crash...

Comment: Sergio, that is what I am worried about. The screen (simulator) freezes, but on xcode it says that it is still running. How would I schedule it after I load the spritesheet? I think I am doing this because my enemy is walking, but then freezes 3s later.

Comment: would you put some NSLog in your main `update` method so that you can see if this runs?

Comment: While the app is "frozen" the log keeps saying this.
AppName[18031:c503] *** Assertion failure in -[AppName addChild:z:tag:], /Developer/Apps/AppName /libs/cocos2d/CCNode.m:388
I'm guessing that means that the addEnemy method failed?

Comment: yes, it seems that you are passing a nil pointer to addChild... either you set a breakpoint on that line, so you stop just there before the assert, or you put a breakpoint on you addEnemy/addChild to see that the pointer you are passing is not nil, or understand why it is nil...

Comment: I'm also getting this message in the log. `AppName[18098:c503] cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Trying to use file 'normalEnemySheet.png' as texture`

Comment: That message is not in itself signal of a problem, anyway, if it is the last message you see in the console, then it *might* be that the app hangs in trying to access the texture... this happened to me once, when due to a memory warning my sprite sheet was being deallocated *before* I could use the texture... but in your case, it seems to me that you are having problems in creating the sprite, so you try and add a `nil` child; this could also be because you have a mismatch with the actual sprite name in the .plist...

Comment: When I debug, I get _NSAssert( child != nil, @"Argument must be non-nil");_ when I step into [self addChild]; of this method
http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1d81

Comment: It is possible that in line 17, `spriteWithSpriteFrameName` i returning nil. The sprite name you use seems suspect to me. I generate sprite sheets using  zwoptex and the sprite name are like: "basename.x.png"; have you checked your sprite names in normalMoleSheet.plist? then, you are adding the sprite both to the batch sprite *and* to `self`... I am not sure you can add the same sprite as child to two nodes...